# How to read two files from one folder?

Tags: java

The code given below takes two different inputs but I want to pass only single input that is the path of folder "test" and rest of the functioning as it is.
And also the final.tbl which is generation it should generate in the same input folder path:

```
public class Migrator {
private static final String KEY1 = "post_tran_id";
private static final String KEY2 = "post_tran_cust_id";

void migrate(String post_tran, String post_tran_cust) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> h1 = loadFile(post_tran, KEY1);
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> h2 = loadFile(post_tran_cust, KEY2);

    PrintStream out = new PrintStream("final.tbl");

    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : h1.entrySet()) {
        Map<String, String> data = entry.getValue();
        String k = data.get(KEY2);
        if (k != null && h2.containsKey(k)) {
            print(out, KEY1, data.get(KEY1));
            print(out, KEY2, data.get(KEY2));
            // Print remaining rows in any order
            for (String key : data.keySet()) {
                if ( ! key.equals(KEY1) && ! key.equals(KEY2) ) {
                    print(out, key, data.get(key));
                }
            }
            data = h2.get(k);
            for (String key : data.keySet()) {
                if ( ! key.equals(KEY2) ) {
                    print(out, key, data.get(key));
                }
            }
            out.println(); // Record separator
        }
    }
 }

 private void print(PrintStream out, String key, String data) {
    out.print("[name]");
    out.print(key);
    out.print("[/name]");
    out.print("=");
    out.print("[data]");
    out.print(data);
    out.print("[/data]");
    out.println();
 }

private Map<String, Map<String, String>> loadFile(String fileName, String key) throws 
 IOException {
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>> 
 ();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line;

    do {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
            data.put(getKey(line), getData(line));
        }

        result.put(data.get(key), data);
    } while (line != null);

    br.close();

    return result;
}

private String getKey(String line) {
    String[] tokens = line.split("=");
    int length = tokens[0].length();
    return tokens[0].substring(6, length - 7);
}

private String getData(String line) {
    String[] tokens = line.split("=");
    int length = tokens[1].length();
    return tokens[1].substring(6, length - 7);
}



 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { Migrator mg =
 new Migrator();

 mg.migrate("D:\\test\\post_tran.tbl",
 "D:\\test\\post_tran_cust.tbl"); }

 }
```

Comment: and your problem is ?

Comment: do you mean that post_tran and post_tran_cust are on the same folder?

Comment: which version of java you are using ?

Comment: Do you mean changing `migrate(String post_tran, String post_tran_cust)` to `migrate(String path)` then this line `loadFile(forceSlash(path)+'post_tran.tbl', KEY1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your **migrate** method take 1 argument but be able to work with many paths, you can always append all the paths into one string and parse them inside the **migrate** method.

**Example:**

```
String appendedArgument = "D:\\test\\post_tran.tbl;D:\\test\\post_tran_cust.tbl";
```

*Notice the semi-colon separating both paths.*

Then you can call you method:

```
mg.migrate(appendedArgument);
```

And parse it on the other side:

```
void migrate(String argument) throws IOException
{
     String[] splitArgument.split(";");

     String post_tran = splitArgument[0];
     String post_tran_cust = splitArgument[1];

     Map<String, Map<String, String>> h1 = loadFile(post_tran, KEY1);
     Map<String, Map<String, String>> h2 = loadFile(post_tran_cust, KEY2);
}
```

Using this kind of method you can send as many paths into your migrate method as you want, this enables you (in this particular case) to also send the path where you want to store the **final.tbl** file.

That would make the appendedArgument string to look like:

```
String appendedArgument = "D:\\test\\;D:\\test\\post_tran.tbl;D:\\test\\post_tran_cust.tbl";
```

And then you would need to parse it accordingly inside the **migrate** method.

Comment: Are you aware of Javas varargs feature?

Comment: I am, but I don't find it easier to understand at a first glance compared to my answer. However, it is also a good solution for this problem.